# Git Branch is not a remote Branch in Stash

Tags: git, branch, remote-server, git-stash

I have a problem with GIT (version 1.8.5.6) in combination with stash. I have created local branches on my development system with the command

```
 git checkout -b <my new branch>
```

After all I pushed my new branch to the remote stash server :

```
 git push -u origin <my new branch>
```

Now I am not able to checkout my new branch on my testsystem, because the branches in Stash are not remote branches. If I run the following commands,
I do not see all branches:

```
git branch -a
```

or

```
git branch -r
```

In the result my branches in stash are not created as remote branches. 
Now I have two questions.
How does it it comes that my branches aren't remote branches?

And

Is it possible to change the branches and convert them to remote ones?

Here are some further information:

```
git remote show
 --> origin
git ls-remote
 --> shows all branches including that ones I have pushed from my dev system.
```

Thank you for your recommendation,

best regards
Jörn

Comment: OK, I think I have solved the problem by myself. My local repository was corrupt in some way. I deleted my local repo including the .git directory. After that I cloned the remote repository. In the following I was able to checkout the newest branch from the Stash server.

Answer (score 0):

Git is (mostly) an offline tool. Your testsystem has no knowledge of the newly created branch on the remote until it contacts the remote. Your `git ls-remote` does that, and hence sees the new branch.

You can `git fetch --all` to have your local git know about all tags and branches that exist upstream.

By re-cloning your repository, you effectively did the same: fetch all remote tags and branches, but you re-downloaded all objects that you already had.

The reverse is not true however: `git fetch --all` does not remove branches that no longer exist upstream. For that you need `git remote prune origin`.